# Windows 10 start menu not saving changes

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

*Hardware: I am using a brand new Lenovo Yoga 720*

I just purchased this laptop and am going through the routine update process and adding applications such as Skype desktop and the Eclipse IDE.

**The issue is when I pin a program to the start menu it will appear, but when I try to pin another program the start menu will close. Upon re-open the pin programs are un-pinned.**

**Edit:** When I try changing the personalization settings of the start menu the same thing happens. I change the settings and upon re-open of the settings window everything is reset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try renaming the Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore` to something else, for example `CloudStore.bak`. Afterwards, log out and log in again. The key will be regenerated, and you will lose some settings (night light, personalizations in the Settings app) along with your Start menu layout.

Comment: This seemed to work, but upon a shut down and boot up cycle the issue presents itself again.

Comment: Could you try killing Explorer.exe before deleting the key to see if it works?

Comment: Do you mean restarting Explorer.exe through the task manager and then resetting the key?

Comment: Try this procedure: open Regedit, end Explorer.exe (don't restart it yet), delete the key with Regedit, and then start Explorer again.

Comment: Hell yeah! Smart solution

Comment: This worked for me. I struggled with a weird Windows 10 install issue for a solid five hours - the Start Menu was loaded with junk icons for Candy Crush Saga, NetFlix, FitBit, etc. - there was no uninstall option, they didn't appear as PowerShell installed packages, etc. Nothing worked until I tried this, which fixed the issue. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score -2):

Make the new user account with administrative privileges,
Login to new administrative account,
Go to control panel user accounts and delft the old-curated account.

Comment: First, you'll notice this question has already been answered, that answer has been accepted as correct, and it is a very different answer from what you have posted. Second, suggesting creating new accounts as administrator is generally considered to be very bad advice unless it is actually necessary, which there is no evidence it is necessary in this situation. If the issue is with the account profile (very likely) then creating a new profile will fix the problem WITHOUT setting up the new account as administrator.