# Windows 10 Tile Layout Only replicating when connected to domain

Tags: start-menu

We're having a slightly weird issue with our machines. It seems that whenever laptop's disconnect from the domain and travel off site, they loose their custom tile layout in start and instead receive a standard layout.

This obviously isn't an issue for domain computers however I would like to retain the layout for laptop users when off-site. Home areas and profiles are configured to sync so I'm at a loss to see why we're loosing the settings.

This has been driving me mad! Would appreciate your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be an issue with caching in Windows 10. While not identical it sounds very similar to either this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/1212927/windows-10-tile-layout-in-start-menu-resets-after-reboot) or this [article](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1758607-windows-10-start-layout) and both give detailed instructions on how to fix either issue.

Comment: Afraid neither articles helped....